# Event Counts from Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset that lists multiple project activities that have start and stop datetimes. I would like to count the number of stops/stops in each months as well as to keep track of cumulative count.
Input:

| project | activity | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Proj1 | act1 | 2020-05-01 08:00:00 | 2020-10-15 08:00:00 |
| Proj1 | act2 | 2020-05-05 08:00:00 | 2020-06-17 08:00:00 |
| Proj1 | act3 | 2020-06-21 17:00:00 | 2020-09-02 17:00:00 |
| Proj2 | act1 | 2021-07-01 08:00:00 | 2021-10-15 08:00:00 |
| Proj1 | act4 | 2020-05-05 08:00:00 | 2021-06-17 08:00:00 |
| Proj2 | act3 | 2021-06-21 17:00:00 | 2021-08-30 17:00:00 |

I would like the output to look like this:

| project | Month | Monthly_Starts | Cumulative_Starts | Monthly_Stops | Cumulative_Stops |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Proj1 | May-2020 | 3 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| Proj1 | Jun-2020 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 2 |
| Proj1 | Jul-2020 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 2 |
| Proj1 | Aug-2020 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 2 |
| Proj1 | Sep-2020 | 0 | 4 | 1 | 3 |
| Proj1 | Oct-2020 | 0 | 4 | 1 | 4 |
| Proj1 | Nov-2020 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 4 |
| Proj2 | May-2020 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Proj2 | Jun-2020 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Proj2 | Jul-2020 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| Proj2 | Aug-2020 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| Proj2 | Sep-2020 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| Proj2 | Oct-2020 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| Proj2 | Nov-2020 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 2 |

I unsuccessfully tried

```
COUNT(start/end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY project,start/end_date)...
```

Please help.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry about that. I guess, we were editing at the same time. I will try to incorporate your changes right now. Thank you!

Comment: I recommend a [mre] with sample data as DDL+DML and your full SQL (maybe as a DBFiddle) as that makes it much easier for others to assist.

Comment: Since my answer got downvoted ("should be a suggestion") and my suggestion is too long as a comment, I can just give you the hint of using a "tally table".